2nd set of coordinates of \begin{picture}(w,h)(x,y) relation to \put[x1,y1]
In a book by Lamport writes the 2nd set of coordinates of \begin{picture}(w,h)(x,y) that the x,y are coordinates of the lower-left corner. So now it seems that in command \put{x1,y1} the x1,y1 are always with respect to the origin assumed at 0,0 at lower left corner and are unaffected by the 2nd set (x,y) because if already have a \put... object the object moves left and downward as the x,y in \begin{picture}(w,h)(x,y) are increased that is become more positive.
So that's the only way i can understand it. So is that correct ?
BUT there is a problem thinking about it like the above because relative to the already written text and equations etc. stay in same place. For example in basic document mode i guess you would call it,making the 2nd of the 2nd set of 2 numbers for example the y offset more negative the objects in the picture , assuming we are putting objects such as line,vector or circle for example (not positively sure about \fbox.. etc. but would assume same goes for that), are moved upwards on the screen and in fact the lowest or last of those writings in document mode could be deleted. So the best way i can think of it is opposite what Lamport wrote.
I would say the origin of the picture say bottom left corner are moved to the right and downward by the amount of the 2nd set of numbers and the \put... command is then relative to the new x,y coordinates. Because what is important is the picture relative to the already written items before and not in picture environment. For example in the 2nd set of numbers x,y is how much the origin is shifted to the left and downward because what is important is relative to the already written stuff in basic document mode prior to going in the picture mode and thinking about it this way the \put.. coordinates ARE relative to the new origin. So the x,y values in the 2nd set denote how far to the left and downward the origin is wrt. 0,0. eg it is moved x units to the left and y units downward from 0,0. And the \put{x1,y1} is x1 units to the right and  y1 units upward wrt the current origin which is if 2nd set of numbers
is x,y the new current origin is x units to the left and y units down from 0,0.

It is very hard to understand your question, tex placed boxes such that their reference points are all on the same horizontal baseline, the second pair changes the reference point of the picture box, that is what the latex book says and that's how it is implemented.

@Davud Carlisle  Ok now i can understand origin moving to the right and upward by an amount of the 2nd argument to \begin{picture} if it means also the origin for all else such as in document mode written prior to \begin{picture} is also moved by that amount.

it just affects the picture anything before that has already been typeset and can;t be moved

Not sure I understood what the question is.
Here is an example with exactly identical outputs.
edit: this is supposed to demonstrate that the second pair of coordinates does matter, because in second picture I had to shift all \put's, and once this is done I obtained exact same output, but using distinct inputs. I hope this is not too confusingly expressed ;-).
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\setlength\unitlength{0.5cm}

\fbox{\begin{picture}(10,10)(0,0)
  \put(0,0){X}  \put(1,1){Y} \put(2,2){Z}
\end{picture}}

\fbox{\begin{picture}(10,10)(1,1)
  \put(1,1){X} \put(2,2){Y} \put(3,3){Z}
\end{picture}}
\end{document}

In second picture the coordinates of bottom left corner of picture (which is invisible here, the border is 3pt distant from it due do the default \fboxsep used by \fbox{}) are (1,1) so I shifted all put's by this.


The second optional argument in () is placing the reference point that is placed on the surrounding baseline. In particular everything left and below of that point is overprinting in that direction without its size considered. This doesn't affect the drawing canvas size specified in the first argument, but alters the point from which that size is measured (so \begin{picture}(2,2)(1,3) will be 2 x 2 big, but its lower left and upper right corner points are (1,3) and (3,5)).
This doesn't alter the placement of material in \put inside the drawing canvas, (0,0) will still be the origin in that coordinate system, but since the reference point for output and size is shifted might lie outside the reserved space of the picture.
The following illustrates this. Note that the placement of the dots surrounding the picture are always the same (and show the approximate baseline -- they are a bit above it), just like the \fbox drawn tightly around the pictures, but the four points end up on different spots relative to that:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\newcommand\bgfbox[2][red]
  {%
    \leavevmode
    \begingroup
      \sbox0{#2}%
      \rlap{\color{#1}\fbox{\phantom{\usebox{0}}}}%
      \usebox{0}%
    \endgroup
  }

\begin{document}
\setlength\unitlength{5mm}
\setlength\fboxsep{-\fboxrule}

.\bgfbox{\begin{picture}(2,2)(0,0)
  \put(0,0){1}
  \put(1,0){2}
  \put(1,1){3}
  \put(0,1){4}
\end{picture}}.

.\bgfbox{\begin{picture}(2,2)(1,0)
  \put(0,0){1}
  \put(1,0){2}
  \put(1,1){3}
  \put(0,1){4}
\end{picture}}.

.\bgfbox{\begin{picture}(2,2)(1,1)
  \put(0,0){1}
  \put(1,0){2}
  \put(1,1){3}
  \put(0,1){4}
\end{picture}}.

.\bgfbox{\begin{picture}(2,2)(0,1)
  \put(0,0){1}
  \put(1,0){2}
  \put(1,1){3}
  \put(0,1){4}
\end{picture}}.
\end{document}


